# Any way to see an output in node-red?

Tags: node-red

I'm a beginner in node-red and I have to continue a project already started.

I want to do some "checkpoint testing" to see what's in some variables; are there any ways to print the values of variables (in the javascript nodes)? And where can we see the output then?

Thank you, Etienne

Comment: Do you mean in a function node? or are you developing your own node?

Comment: Yes in the function node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Node-RED docs. http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#logging-events

You can use `node.log()`. `node.warn()` or `node.error()` to output information from with in a function node.